# How to query that matches two conditions in aws dynamodb?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query table in dynamoDB that matches two conditions. Table looks like this

```
{
  {"id": "1", "name": "John"}, 
  {"id": "2", "name": "John"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "Bob"}
}
```

I want to query `where id = 1 and name = John`

How can i do this in AWS lambda using node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `id` is the partition key and that `name` is a non key attribute.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-west-2" });

const query = async () => {
  const response = await documentClient
    .query({
      TableName: "myTable",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#pk": "id",
        "#n": "name"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk": "1",
        ":n": "john",
      },
      FilterExpression: "#n = :n",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#pk = :pk",
    })
    .promise();

  console.log(`Query response: ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);
};

query().catch((error) => console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)))
```

Comment: can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643567/how-to-insert-an-object-in-dynamodb-if-condition-matches/76644204#76644204