# How to insert an object in dynamoDB if condition matches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to enter an object into `teams` field but it's overwriting existing one. What am i doing wrong here?

**table**

```
{
 {
  id: '1', // PK
  name: 'basketball',
  teams: {}
 },
 {
  id: '2', // PK
  name: 'soccer',
  teams: {}
 }
}
```

**current code**

```
let team = {
    TableName: table,
    Key: {id: event.gameId},
    UpdateExpression: `SET teams = :n`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
         ":n":{[event.teamId]: {teamId: event.teamId, teamName: event.teamName}},
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
                    
try {
     await dbClient.update(teamBody).promise();
     return { statusCode: 200, message: "Success"};
} catch (err){
     return {error: err};
}
```

**expected result**

```
{
 id: '1', // PK
 name: 'basketball',
 teams: {
   '1': {teamId:'1', teamName: 'Blue'},
   '2': {teamId:'2', teamName: 'Red'},
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let team = {
    TableName: table,
    Key: {id: event.gameId},
    UpdateExpression: `SET #t.#n = :n`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
         ":n":{teamId: event.teamId, teamName: event.teamName},
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#t":"teams",
        "#n": [event.teamId]
    }
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
                    
try {
     await dbClient.update(teamBody).promise();
     return { statusCode: 200, message: "Success"};
} catch (err){
     return {error: err};
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks Lee Hannigan

Comment: can i get your eyes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671427/how-to-delete-nested-item-in-dynamodb-using-node

Comment: Answered the question. It's from my phone but should be somewhat correct syntax wise.

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating to the teams attribute index of your item before performing the update. You need to go one level deeper in your SET to ‘SET teams.#teamId = :n’.

[Update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) is a great page to review for your use case. Review the sections on adding lists, maps, and there’s a section about working with nested attributes that you might find useful.

Comment: getting this error now
 "message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #teamId",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).