# How to delete nested item in DynamoDB using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete an item from `teams` object.

**My game table looks like this**

```
{
   gameId: "1", //PK
   teams: {
     1: {id: "1", teamName: "Blue"},
     2: {id: "2", teamName: "Red"}
   }
}
```

**My code looks like this**

```
let team = {
   TableName: table,
   Key: {id: event.pathParameters.gameId},
   ConditionExpression: "#t.#n = :val",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#t":"teams",
        "#n": event.pathParameters.teamId
   },
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":val" : event.pathParameters.teamId,
         "#n": event.pathParameters.teamId
   }
};
                        
try {
   
  await dbClient.delete(team).promise();

} catch (err){
                            
  return {error: err};

}
```

**But i am getting following error**

`The conditional request failed`

**What am i doing wrong???**

Comment: You are mixing DynamoDB terminology with JavaScript terminology and it is making your questions more difficult for readers. It's worth reviewing the basic DynamoDB [concepts](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/key-concepts) of table, item, attribute, value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to delete an attribute within an item, and not a whole item, so your fundamentals are wrong here

```
let team = {
   TableName: table,
   Key: {id: event.pathParameters.gameId},
   UpdateExpression: "remove #t.#n",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#t":"teams",
        "#n": event.pathParameters.teamId
   }
};
                        
try {
   
  await dbClient.update(team).promise();

} catch (err){
                            
  return {error: err};

}
```

Comment: thanks @Lee Hannigan it works. I am trying to learn no-sql stuff. it's very confusing. Do you have any recommendation on no-sql tutorial?

Comment: Two things that I can suggest to help is AcloudGuru course on DynamoDB and also Alex DeBries DynamoDB Book, both are great resources for beginners.